# Join is not joining appropriately

Tags: join

I'm trying to join the two files below:

FileA.txt:

```
ABCA1   0   2
ABCA4   3   12
ABCB11  0   4
ABCB4   0   3
ABCC6   0   3
ABCC8   4   33
```

FileB.txt

```
ABCA4   2
ABCB11  1
```

Where there isn't a match in the second file I want a 0 printed. I've tried this join command:

```
join -a 1 -a 2 -e '0' -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2 FileA.txt FileB.txt
```

However, this prints 0's for all of the entries in the new 3rd column. As so:

```
ABCA1 0 2 0
ABCA4 3 12 0
ABCB11 0 4 0
ABCB4 0 3 0
ABCC6 0 3 0
```

I used a version of this command to generate my FileA.txt. I'm not sure why it won't work to add a third column. Any help?

Comment: I can't reproduce your output.  Using your command and your sample files I see 2 and 1 for the third column for the expected lines

Comment: @EricRenouf Could it be a problem with my version of join?

Comment: I suppose it could be, on occasion people have posted working code and tested the wrong thing on their own, so I'd confirm that you are really seeing that result with those files.  I have tried it on 3 different flavors of linux myself

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of `join` changes when locale environment variables are set. Try your `join` after doing `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` or `export LC_ALL=C`.

Comment: I ran my command with `LC_ALL=C join -a 1 -a 2 -e '0' -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2 FileA.txt FileB.txt`. Should that suffice?

Comment: @stellar01 - Yes, that should work, if locale is the problem.

Comment: Even with the adjustment, I fail to get the appropriate result. I don't understand why it won't work. I was able to successfully use this command a couple months ago, but I can no longer use it now :( I guess I'll switch to `awk`